# How to remove first 5 characters from this string?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a string like this (HTML select list):

```
const config = {
    "celsius": {
        "celsius": v => v,
        "fahrenheit": v => v * 1.8 + 32,
        "kelvin": v => v + 273.15,
        "rankine": v => (v + 273.15) * 1.8,
        "reaumur": v => v * 0.8,
    },
    // more...
}
```

And I want to cut the first 5 characters from the output (operationPlace)

```
var listOperation = config[listFromV][listToV].substring(5);
document.getElementById("operationPlace").innerHTML = listOperation;
// now it looks like this: v => v or v => v * 1.8 + 32 etc.
// should look like this: v or v * 1.8 + 32 etc. (I'd like to change that "v" to numbers from the input (inputPlace) too)
```

I tried using substring, but it didn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what is the content of listFromV and listToV ?

Comment: `// now it looks like this: v => v or v => v * 1.8 + 32 etc.` - that would only make sense, if your data contained these as _string_ values in the first place - but that doesn't match what you have shown us. Please present a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, and also show us how you tried to use substring.

Comment: Please tell us what output you would expect for what input. What is "the output" you mentioned? And please show us the `substring` code that did not work for you.

Comment: What about `document.getElementById("operationPlace").innerHTML = listOperation.toString().substring(5)`?

Comment: document.getElementById("operationPlace").innerHTML = listOperation.toString().substring(5) - this works just fine, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the definition of a function in the form of a string by calling `.toString` on it, then call `.substring` to get rid of the function signature part:

```
var listOperation = config[listFromV][listToV];
document.getElementById("operationPlace").innerHTML = listOperation.toString().substring(5);
```

Note that this is approach is naive and will only work for functions whose signature is composed of a single 1-character long argument and arrow notation without parenthesis.